# Distance between waterway labels in CartoCSS

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

How can I manage distance between waterway labels (names of rivers) in cartoCSS?[image]

Comment: would be helpful if you copied in your carto.

Comment: also, is this TileMill or MapBox Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a full list of CartoCSS properties in the *Docs* panel in MapBox Studio.  (assuming you're in MapBox Studio?)

The Carto properties you should be interested in are:

- `text-min-path-length`
- `text-min-distance`

`text-min-distance` will only limit the distance from one label to the next **on the same line segment**.  `text-min-path-length` will limit the size of a line segment that has labels added to it.  Because features (in your case, the river centerline) are broken into segments--usually of different sizes--it's difficult to ensure completely uniform label placement on lines.  By varying those two properties, you can usually do a good enough job.

Ultimately, if you need more control, you would need to edit the geometry of that line by merging each segment into one feature.